# Is modifying data already inserted to crossfilter possible?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter, dc.js

Looking at the [Crossfilter API](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference), I don't see any mention of how to modify rows already added to Crossfilter.

Is it absolutely forbidden/impossible to modify existing rows? Say, by adding a few more fields or by modifying a field value of a row? Seems that removing all data and readding it to crossfilter is the only way, but that would mean losing all current filters, dimensions etc.

Comment: That's right, you'd need to remove and re-add them to get them updated in the indices. Otherwise it would get inconsistent.

Comment: @Gordon. Right, I was afraid of that. In other words, I need to do crossfilterInstance.remove() followed by crossfilterInstance.add(newRecordsWithMoreFields). I'm willing to accept that as an answer here.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a 'unique dimension' that returns a unique value for every entry in your dataset (like an ID column), you can have a function like this to make changes to a single entry without throwing off everything:

```
function editEntry(id, changes) {
    uniqueDimension.filter(id); // filter to the item you want to change
    var selectedEntry = uniqueDimension.top(1)[0]; // get the item
    _.extend(selectedEntry, changes); // apply changes to it
    ndx.remove(); // remove all items that pass the current filter (which will just be the item we are changing
    ndx.add([selectedEntry]); // re-add the item
    uniqueDimension.filter(null); // clear the filter
    dc.redrawAll(); // redraw the UI
}
```